# AngularJs json URL changer

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, url

I'm working on some mega simple weather app in Angular for practice reasons and i'm stuck..

i have a angular json feed like this:

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Amsterdam,NL&lang=NL_nl&units=metric') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

and it loads the feed in to the index.html. its all working and what i wand now is a input form on index that changes the **Amsterdam** part of the url on js/services/forcast.js where the above code is to another city so people can see their city weather.

See the demo here: http://dev.bigstoef.nl/workspace/shiva/weer/index.html

Ive tryd about all posable options about now and i'm 3 days further and its a no go. What is there correct way here?

Comment: What is the controller code?

Comment: `app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) {
  forecast.success(function(data) {
    $scope.weer = data;
  });
}]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a "configurable" service :

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
    var city;
    var cities = {
        amsterdam: 'Amsterdam,NL',
        paris: 'Paris,FR'
    };
    var api_base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
    var other_params = 'lang=NL_nl&units=metric';

    return {
        setCity: function(cityName){
            city = cityName ;
            console.log(city);
        },
        getWeather: function(cityName){
          console.log(city);
            if(cityName) this.setCity(cityName);
            if (!city) throw new Error('City is not defined');
            return $http.get(getURI());
        }
    }

    function getURI(){
        return api_base_url + '?' + cities[city] + '&' + other_params;
    }
}]);
```

Then you can create a controller like the following:

```
app.controller('forecastCtrl', ['$scope', 'forecast',function($scope,forecast){

$scope.city = 'amsterdam' ;

    $scope.$watch('city',function(){
      console.log($scope.city);
      forecast.setCity($scope.city);
    });

$scope.getWeather = function(){
  console.log('get weather');
    forecast.getWeather()
    .success(function(data){
    console.log('success',data);
    $scope.weatherData = data;
    }).error(function(err){
      console.log('error',err);
      $scope.weatherError = err; 
    });    
}; 
}]);
```

To implement a template as the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

```
<div data-ng-controller="forecastCtrl">

  <form>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="city" data-ng-model="city" data-ng-value="'amsterdam'">Amsterdam
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="city" data-ng-model="city" data-ng-value="'paris'">Paris
    </label>
    <br/>

    <button data-ng-click="getWeather()">Get Weather</button>

  </form>  

  <p class="weather-data">
    {{weatherData}}
  </p>
  <p class="weather-error">
    {{weatherError}}
  </p>

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

You can view the code working here : http://plnkr.co/edit/rN14M8GGX62J8JDUIOl8?p=preview

Comment: I cant get this to work.... http://dev.bigstoef.nl/workspace/shiva/weer/index.html?

Comment: It seems you missed to include your ForecastCtrl in your index.html or you mispelled it (upper case ?). In my example code I used lower case `forecastCtl`. In the template and in the js. But in your index.html, you used uppercase `<script src="js/controllers/ForecastCrtl.js"></script>`. Replace it by `<script src="js/controllers/forecastCrtl.js"></script>` to get working

Comment: i see. thats kinda dumb of me.. yet i changed it all and still a no go... what am i doing wrong here....

Comment: Ok there is syntax error in the controller. See Edit CTRL in my post.

Comment: You just removed the whole CTRL ... just replace the first $scope.getWeather function by the new one

Comment: And now, you missed to close the `$scope.getWeather`  function `}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78772/discussion-between-shiva-traanman-and-remi-becheras).

Answer (score 1):

Change service code to have a dedicated method which you can call multiple times with different parameters (cities):

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        load: function(location) {
            return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location + '&lang=NL_nl&units=metric')
            .success(function(data) {
                return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                return err;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then in controller you would be able to load forecat for other locations when you need:

```
forecast.load('Amsterdam,NL').then(function(data) {
    $scope. weer = data;
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GCx35VxRoko314jJ3M7r?p=preview

Comment: ok i get this code! sorry for being a MEGA noob. but how do i change the "location" now trough a input form?

Comment: It depends on your application. In my demo I provided simple input field to enter location. It can be dropdown, or anything else. Check the demo.

Comment: ive tryd but i cant seems to get it in to my code.... when i do angular stops working...

Answer (score 1):

You can return a function in your factory. Define your `forcast` as

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
 return {
     query: function(city) {
         return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&lang=NL_nl&units=metric') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        });
     }
 };

}]);
```

Then in your controller

```
forecast.query('Amsterdam,NL').success(function(data) {
  $scope.weer = data;
});
```